# Error when I try to test a local Meteor package

Tags: javascript, meteor

Hi everyone I am new in Meteor programing and I am folowing the online book discovermeteor.com

There is a chapter which talk about Creating Meteor Packages

I am able to create the package using the command **meteor create --package errors**

But when I try to add this package to my my application I receive the folowing error

*=> Errors while parsing arguments:
While adding package errors:
error: no such package*

And the folowing error when I try to test it

*=> Errors while collecting tests:
While trying to test package `errors`:
error: Not a known local package, cannot test*

What am I doing wrong?

PS I am using Windows as my development computer

Comment: Would you post the package code?

Answer (score 0):

You should create `packages` directory within the root of your app. If you plan to publish your package, then run the following on your terminal (inside your newly created *packages* directory, of course) `meteor create --package username:your-package-name`. Username is your meteor developer account username. If you don't want to publish it, you can just run `meteor create --package your-package-name`.

Answer (score -2):

If you are trying to add the errors package here (https://atmospherejs.com/tmeasday/errors), use this command:

```
meteor add tmeasday:errors
```

Comment: this just downloads the package(tmeasday:errors) from the atmospherejs, and won't link to the local package. Besides instead of the `tmeasday` part you should put your own unique meteor dev username.